# Losing authentication details on token refresh

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Using spring-security-oauth2 with refresh tokens, i'm having problems getting details (OAuth2Authentication.getDetails()) from the refreshed access_token because they are lost in refreshAccessToken@DefaultTokenServices as i have seen in debug. Details are present before first refresh.

I have seen a fix in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/pull/581 but the changes has not been commited in three years.

I'm surprised there's no more complaints about this topic in 3 years and i would like to know how is people solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, i have been able to solve the problem as follows.

All was a configuration misunderstood, with conflicts between `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and `@EnableResourceServer` definitions.

Setting same configuration in both classes, I was able to solve the problem using custom classes extending`TokenEnhancer` and `JwtAccessTokenConverter`.

I also updated dependencies to last versions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```